# How to make Ribbon Control look the same as Windows 10 File Explorer?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I tried RibbonWindow and I think it's a good stuff.

but when I run it in Windows 10, I've found it not quite like windows10's File Explorer Ribbon:

[image]

for example:

- Icon hover area out of window border(Red block)
- Window title not in the center of title bar (green block)
- There are strange gray borders on the left and right window (blue blocks)

compare with Windows 10 File Explorer(activing window), looks like they are 2 diffence production, am I using the correct one, or there're another better version?(which I cannot found).

Comment: Unfortunately the MS WPF Ribbon has some problems and hasn't been updated for some time. You can try [Fluent Ribbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon) instead.

Comment: They're just in different `theme`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` not RibbonControlsLibrary from nuget

Result as you expect:

[image]